# Cache Android frame animtaion

Tags: android, caching, android-animation

In my app, I have a frame animation right after the splash screen, and sometimes it get stuck for a while before it loads the UI.
Is there a way to load all the bitmaps in the splash screen, cache them, and then use the cached bitmaps in the frame animation?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a global caching mechanism , putting the images while the splash screen starts, and use them later.

the easiest way to cache things is by using [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html).. it's also a dangerous one since you have to clean it when you don't need it.

in order to make the cache a little smart and dispose of old items each time it uses too much memory and you put new items,  you can use [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html). it's for API 12 and above, but you can easily copy its code and adjust it to your needs.

if you need a storage cache, you can use [this one](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache).

also, you might want to check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html), which provides you some information about caching images.

do note that android devices are limited in heap memory, so don't expect to be able to cache a lot of images on all devices. you will have to use some downscaling techniques for low end devices, to use less memory.